# Is there a way to get rid of [Object: null prototype] in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to make one-to-many relationship database with `Mongoose` and `GraphQL`.

Whenever I insert the data to GraphQL mutation argument, I will get `[Object: null prototype]` error.

I notice the object will have `[Object: null prototype]` in front of it when I tried to `console.log` for debug purpose.

I have tried many ways, tried to `map()` args or even to use `replace()` but no luck. All I have been getting is `"args.ingredient.map/replace is not a function"`

I have test hard coded method by changing the args for example:

```
args.category = '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788'
args.ingredient = '5c28c8deb99a9d263462a086'
```

Surprisingly it works with this method. I assume the input cannot be an object but just an ID.

Refer below for actual results.

Resolvers

```
Query: {
    recipes: async (root, args, { req }, info) => {
        return Recipe.find({}).populate('ingredient category', 'name createdAt').exec().then(docs => docs.map(x => x))
    },
},
Mutation: {
    addRecipe: async (root, args, { req }, info) => {
      // args.category = '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788'
      // args.ingredient = '5c28c8deb99a9d263462a086'
      // console.log(args.map(x => x))
      return Recipe.create(args)
    }
}
```

TypeDef

```
extend type Mutation {
    addRecipe(name: String!, direction: [String!]!, ingredient: [IngredientInput], category: [CategoryInput]): Recipe
}

type Recipe {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    direction: [String!]!
    ingredient: [Ingredient!]!
    category: [Category!]!
}

input IngredientInput {
    id: ID!
}

input CategoryInput {
    id: ID!
}
```

Models

```
const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    direction: [String],
    ingredient: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient' }],
    category: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
}, {
    timestamps: true // createdAt, updateAt
})

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema)
```

This is the result I console log the args when inserting the data

```
{ 
    name: 'Butter Milk Chicken TEST2',
    direction: [ 'Step1', 'Step2', 'Step3' ],
    ingredient:[[Object: null prototype] { id: '5c28c8d6b99a9d263462a085' }],
    category: [[Object: null prototype] { id: '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788' }]
}
```

I assume I need to get something like this

```
{ 
    name: 'Butter Milk Chicken TEST2',
    direction: [ 'Step1', 'Step2', 'Step3' ],
    args.category = ['5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788']
    args.ingredient = ['5c28c8ccb99a9d263462a083', '5c28c8d3b99a9d263462a084', '5c28c8d6b99a9d263462a085']
}
```

Comment: Where would the arrays come from?

Comment: Where exactly do you "*get [Object: null prototype] error*", in the `Recipe.create` line? Can you post the full error message, please

Comment: I filed as an issue in the apollo project: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3149

Comment: This has been very quickly fixed in firestore. https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/pull/736

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We had this problem. We were looking to query a service object in the database that had a price on it.

Expected Result:

```
service: {
  price: 9999
}
```

However, we accidentally queried “services” (instead of “service”) which gave us an array of prices (with only one price) like so:

`[ [Object: null prototype] { price: 9.99 } ]`

This was caused by a bad query.

Once we changed the query to “service” (instead of “services”) the data came back as expected without the null prototype.

We use Prisma as our ORM though but perhaps you are querying for recipes when you should be querying for recipe.

Comment: I get the null prototype when I run a create mutation and return the results as well, so not sure if it's a naming thing.

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like below,and [Object: null prototype] would disappear

```
const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args));
```

`args.category` is

```
[[Object: null prototype] { id: '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788' }],
```

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args.category) would be  `{ id: '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788' }`

Comment: Please include some explanation for your answer.

Comment: @amanb the reason why this works it's because you first use `JSON.strigify(args)` transforming the value of args from [[Object: null prototype] { id: '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788' }] to [{ id: '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788' }] and then with the `JSON.parse` you transform it to a valid JS value. In my case I prefered to do `JSON.strigify(args[0])` to achieve the needed result of  `{ name: 'test', type: 'A' }`

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when passing InputTypes as an argument, I solve it using destructuring, like this:

```html
addRecipe: async (root, { ...args }, { req }, info) => {
   // args.category = '5c28c79af62fad2514ccc788'
   // args.ingredient = '5c28c8deb99a9d263462a086'
   // console.log(args.map(x => x))
   return Recipe.create(args)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with the **args** parameter. Your problem happens because **args** is an object that holds the mutation arguments. After destructuring it, you're gonna be able to access your argument directly:

```
Mutation: {
    addRecipe: async (root, { args }, { req }, info) => {
      return Recipe.create(args)
    }
}
```